# Codeeffects internal error on GetClientSettings() when using Source XML without persisting the source

Tags: asp.net-core, rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I'm trying to use Source XML (I have CodeEffects 5.0.12 Nuget in a ASP.NET Core 2.2 Project) without a known type at design time. So I set persisted="false" and type="" in the SourceXml. Everything works great with fields, but if I define a function, I get an internal "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when calling ruleEditor.GetClientSettings() -> this is mandatory for loading the web editor. Is there any extra setting that I'm missing or Source XML does not allow functions? Or maybe this is a known issue and some workaround is required?

Comment: Update your NuGet references to version 5.0.14.6

Comment: Updated to 5.0.14.6, but I still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the latest release.